# Permalink for specific post type

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, permalinks

A client has a WordPress website (4.8.13) running with the **default** post types and some **custom** post types.
He wants to change the **permalinks** to use the **post title**, but only for the `post` post type.

If I change the permalink settings in wp-admin, will it change to **all** post types, or just for `post`? If it changes for all post types, how I can change the permalink settings only for `post` post type?

Answer (score 0):

If it is an option to use a plugin, here is one with over 100,000 installs, so it seems to do a good job:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/

It is exactly solving your client's wish. After installing and activating it, go to Settings -> Permalinks -> and scroll down to the section Permalink Settings for Custom Post Types.